# getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist error when trying to build with stack

Tags: haskell-stack

I need to **import Graphics.UI.Gtk** and **GHC** suggests:

> Perhaps you need to add ‘text’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.

but I use **stack**, so I add **gtk** to extra-deps, execute **stack build** and get **../gtk/: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist (No such file or directory)**.

How can I add dependency with **stack**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the version number of your extra deps in the stack.yaml file, something like:

```
extra-deps
- gtk-X.Y.Z
```